# Implementation of Dynamic meta tags in react js with php backend and redux

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, react-redux, react-helmet

It really gets complicated when trying to add dynamic meta data such as title, description, og_image etc in reactJs. when I use react-meta-tags package, the title changes, i can see the meta data changed on the Inspector of my browser but when I share on websites like facebook, WhatsApp etc, I only get the meta data found in the default Index.html

I am using redux in my application and I am usisng a PHP (Yii2) backend making the server side params as seen from research online a far fetch dream . Any Ideas on how to resolve this issue will be greatly appreciated.

```
                    <MetaTags>
                        <title>{m.name}</title>
                        <meta name="description" content={mdetails} />
                        <meta property="og:title" content={name} />
                        <meta property="og:image" content={apiConstants.API_FILES+m.cover} />
                    </MetaTags>
```

Comment: Have you found a solution for this yet? I have the same issue and am using react-helmet

Answer (score 0):

I can see your problem, I would consider using `react-helmet`.

You can declare changes without any custom intervention.

https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet

Comment: react-helmet and react-meta-tag functions the same way. I have tried it and it behaves the same

Comment: I misread your question, have you considered using Gatsby as the file is generated at build time, so Seo will pick it up?

Comment: Have not use that before. direction on that will help

Comment: Gatsbyjs is another new framework and will require me to port my entire reactJs code. my application is really big so porting is quite complex